# Difference between calling __init__() of build-in class and __init__() of user-defined class

Tags: python, class, python-object

I am learning python classes and could not understand below behavior:

In below example, I am extending built-in `str` class:

```
class uStr(str):
    def __init__(self,u_str):
        str.__init__(u_str)       #<<<------- no self is needed

    def underline(self):
        underlines = format('', '-^' + str(len(self)))
        return str.__str__(self) + '\n' + underlines
```

In below example, I am extending a user-defined class `Fraction`:

```
from fraction import *

class MixedFraction(Fraction):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        Fraction.__init__(self, args[0], args[1])     #<<<-------self is needed

    def getWholeNum(self):
        return self.getNumerator() // self.getDenominator()
```

Why do we need to give `self` as argument in 2nd example in calling `__init__` of super class, while there is no need to give `self` in calling `str`'s `__init__`.

Comment: "no self is needed" - yeah it is. That `__init__` call is wrong. Confusingly, the argument you were supposed to omit is actually `u_str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need those `__init__` implementations at all. You could just inherit the superclass implementations. If you actually need to customize construction, then for `uStr`, you should do it in `__new__` instead of `__init__`.

---

`str` [doesn't have](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L15203) its own `__init__`. It does all its initialization in `__new__`, because `str` instances are immutable and initializing in `__init__` would be mutative. `str` inherits `__init__` from `object`.

`object.__init__` and `object.__new__` are a little weird. If exactly one of `object.__init__` or `object.__new__` are overridden, then the overridden one throws an error if given arguments (beyond `self`) and the other ignores arguments, to save you the work of having to provide a do-nothing override. However, if both or neither are overridden, then both will throw an error if given arguments (beyond `self`). You can see this explained in a [big comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Objects/typeobject.c#L3658) in the source code.

`str` implements `__new__`, but inherits `__init__` from `object`. When you override `__init__` and call `str.__init__`, you're really calling `object.__init__`.

When you call `str.__init__(u_str)`, you're actually making an `object.__init__` call for `u_str`, the wrong object, rather than for `self`. Since `u_str` doesn't have an `__init__` override (and since you're only passing one argument, which gets interpreted as `self`), `object.__init__` silently does nothing.

When you call `str.__init__(self, u_str)`, you're making an `object.__init__` call for `self`, but since `self` has both `__new__` and `__init__` overridden, `object.__init__` complains about the `u_str` argument.

It doesn't look like you actually need to override construction at all in your subclasses. If you do, the correct way to customize construction of a `str` subclass is to override `__new__`. If for some strange reason you had to call `str.__init__`, the correct call would be `str.__init__(self)` or `super().__init__()`. Since `object.__init__` doesn't do any initialization, you could also leave out the superclass constructor call.

Comment: Thanks @user2357112 supports Monica for the answer. I got some idea from the answer, but I think I still need to go deeper into this to understand more.